# In out parameter : how to execute

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
   Create or replace procedure sma11( a in number ,b1 out varchar2)
   is
 begin
      b1:=mod(&a,2);
    if b1=0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('b1'||'is even');
      else 
       dbms_output.put_line('b1'||'odd');
       end if;
   end;

   begin
   sma11(1000,b1);
   end;
/
```

the above one gives errors, I want to pass a value and get the output       displayed by using parameters. can anyone suggest on this ?

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: its now done as I have removed the &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just change the following line

```
  b1:=mod(&a,2);
```

to (remove the `&`)

```
  b1:=mod(a,2);
```

Hope this helps..

**UPDATED** to provide rationale:  The `&` is not needed in PL/SQL procedures to access input parameters, and I think was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to call the `small` procedure, the answer is that you have to declare the `b1` variable in the caller.

```
declare
  b1 varchar2(10);
begin
  sma11(1000,b1);
end;
```

If you are asking why the procedure doesn't compile (as @vmachan points out), you have an extra `&`

```
  Create or replace procedure sma11( a in number ,
                                    b1 out varchar2)
  is
  begin
    b1:=mod(a,2);
    if b1=0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('b1'||'is even');
    else 
      dbms_output.put_line('b1'||'odd');
    end if;
   end;
```

I am hard-pressed to guess why you would define your `out` parameter to be a `varchar2` when you seem to treat it as a number internally.  It would seem to make more sense to either define `b1` in your procedure as a `number` or to compute a string value.  I am also not sure why you would want to use a procedure for this sort of thing when it would be much more appropriate to put in a function since functions return something.  Functions are, in general, used for calculations that do not change the state of the database.  Procedures are, in general, used for things that manipulate the state of the database.